# Non-standardized Student's t distribution

Tags: terminology, t-distribution

If I compute the quantity
$$
    t = \frac{\mu}{\sigma},
$$
for a mean value $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$ computed from some $n$-vector, $v$, is it then correct to state that $t$ follows a non-standardized Student's t distribution with $n$ degrees of freedom?

Essentially, I want to test if the mean of $v$ is distinguishable from zero, but my question is if the terminology is correct?

Comment: This one's hard to answer without additional information. What is this "$n$-vector $v$"? Are you modeling it as a simple random sample? If so, what assumptions are you making about the underlying distribution? If not, what is your model?

Comment: The vector v contains a statistic computed in a cross-validation procedure. At the core, I'm testing H0: v=0, but at this point I only want to compute the t-values of several independent vs for comparison.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not enough information to determine anything about the distribution $t$ might follow.  At a minimum, you need to explain what this statistic is and what can vary (randomly) during the cross-validation.

Comment: I can safely assume that the elements of $v$ follow a normal distribution. I just want to perform a $t$ test, but the factor $1/\sqrt{n}$ in the standard error is not important since it is the same in all $v$s. My question is: If I drop it, can I describe this using the terminology of my question?